# Detect Keystrokes In Different Window with Batch

Tags: batch-file

Fair people of stack overflow! My question today is how to detect key presses, but not in the batch window itself. I have this code already:

```
choice /c KEY /n /t 5 /d d
if %errorlevel%==1 goto restofcode
```

This *only* works if you select the batch window itself. What I need is a way, in batch (or some other language) to make it detect if you press Ctrl+W *outside* of the actual batch command line itself.

There is a program called GS Auto-Clicker and it starts clicking your mouse when you press a key. I want something like this as far as detecting what key you press.

Comment: Have a look at [trigger an event on key press in windows](http://superuser.com/questions/785245/trigger-an-event-on-key-press-in-windows).

Comment: Could use `GetAsyncKeyState()` from user32.dll.  That will detect a keypress regardless of which window is focused.

Comment: You can add a keyboard hotkey to a shortcut. Then you can put a script.vbs as the target with `createobject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Window Title"`. If you put a hotkey on the shortcut that starts the bat that key will switch to the bat if it's already running.

Comment: Rojo, could you give me an example of how to use GetAsyncKeyState()? I would like to to detect a key press, then run a command. Thanks!

Comment: See `waitfpr` cmd.

Comment: @BatchMan I appreciate that you posted code and demonstrated your efforts to solve this on your own.  I will help you out.

Comment: You can't use API functions in batch so the answer is worthless.

Comment: @Noodles You're welcome to post a more worthwhile answer if you wish.  If it's a programmatic solution and it meets OP's requirements, then you've got my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okie doke, here's an example demonstrating `GetAsyncKeyState()` using a Batch + PowerShell hybrid script.  Save it with a .bat extension.  Hopefully the inline comments sufficiently explain how it works.  [See the MSDN page on `GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) for full details on that function's expected arguments and return value type.

**Edit:** Fixed bugs.  Original answer would trigger if the user pressed and released <kbd>W</kbd> then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.  It seems my PowerShell 2.0 interpreter has some buggy behavior.  Setting variables to the `GetAsyncKeyState()` return value on each loop iteration seems to fix it.  I also made the key definitions a little less neck-beardy by leveraging the [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), and removed the possibility that the "recently pressed" bit would trigger a false positive for "currently pressed".

```perl
<# : batch portion (begins PowerShell multiline comment block)
@echo off & setlocal

set /P "=Waiting for ctrl-W... "<NUL

rem # re-launch self with PowerShell interpreter
powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"

echo Pressed.  Toodles.

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell chimera #>

# import GetAsyncKeyState()
Add-Type user32_dll @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
'@ -namespace System

# for Keys object constants
Add-Type -As System.Windows.Forms

function keyPressed($key) {
    return [user32_dll]::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::$key) -band 32768
}

while ($true) {
    $ctrl = keyPressed "ControlKey"
    $W = keyPressed "W"
    if ($ctrl -and $W) { break }
    start-sleep -milliseconds 40
}

$Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputBuffer()
```

Comment: Here I am a little later and I was using this and it worked fine, but now I get an error "powershell" is not recognized as an internal or external command. I tried to modify it so it looped and it DID work but now it doesn't.

Comment: @BatchMan Sounds like you screwed up your `%PATH%` environment variable.  Does the problem persist through reboots?  If you go to a cmd console and type `where powershell` does the command return a fully qualified path to `powershell.exe`?  If none of this helps, maybe you should post a separate question showing your attempted modifications.

Comment: Hmm, I was messing with paths, when I get a chance, I will try to put it back to the way it was. Thanks!